# What's the grammatical difference between "trotz" und "trotzdem"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

"Trotz" is usually used as "despite", and "trotzdem" is "nevertheless", but:

- What is the grammatical difference?
- Where does the verb go for "trotz" and where does it go for
  "trotzdem"?
- Do Germans use either of these when they speak or is it one of the
  two that you only use when you write?
- Do you use a comma with these?

Comment: Bit of a broad question, maybe split it up a bit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*trotz* is a **preposition** like the English *despite*:

Example:

> Trotz ihrer Schmerzen konnte sie den Marathonlauf beenden.

Since commas aren't needed with prepositions you needn't set one even if the word order changes like in this sentence:

> Thomas feuerte den Mitarbeiter trotz dessen großer Verdienste für die Firma.

---

*trotzdem* can be used as **adverb** or as **conjunction** ([same meaning as *obwohl*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/trotzdem_obzwar_wenngleich) - not used in Standard German anymore).

Example as adverb:

> Obwohl es ihm sein Vater verboten hatte, sah sich Timmy den Horrorfilm trotzdem an.

In the sentence above "trotzdem" is redundant; normally it's used in single sentences. Example:

> Der Vater warnte seinen Sohn vor dem Film. Timmy sah sich den Horrorfilm trotzdem an.

Example conjunction

> Er fuhr mit dem Auto, trotzdem er wusste, dass es kaputt war.

Comment: are you suppose to use genitive with trotz?

Comment: yes, Genitiv: *trotz des starken Regens...*, though in Southern Germany also Dativ; see http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Genitiv.html#Anchor-trotz-30408 "Im Singular meist unflektiert, wenn das Nomen allein steht: *trotz Regen*"

Comment: I'd like to add that the conjunction-trotzdem has to be pronounced differently... it carries a string emphasis on -dem. The adverb has a stress on trotz-

TROTZdem (adv.)
trotzDEM (konj) ... Me personally I need the stress on DEM to be VERY strong in order to undestand the grammaticl structure right away... otherwise I would understand the adverb and later realize that it wasn't (based on sentence structure).

Comment: "Er fuhr mit dem Auto, trotzdem er wusste, dass es kaputt war." sounds a little cumbersome. "Obwohl er wusste" would be more appropriate. Although is a good translation for "obwohl"