# Nevertheless/Nonetheless in German

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice, adverb

Related to [What's the grammatical difference between "trotz" und "trotzdem"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/whats-the-grammatical-difference-between-trotz-und-trotzdem), there are several translation for *nevertheless* or *nonetheless*:

- gleichwohl [formal]
- nichtsdestotrotz [colloquial]
- nichtsdestoweniger
- trotzdem

(from http://goo.gl/19cMdU)

**When do I use which?** For instance, for the following sentence, is using *trotzdem/nichtsdestotrotz* valid.

> *Trotzdem/Nichtsdestotrotz* hat sich die neue Bundesrepublik Deutschland unter amerikanischem Druck an der militärischen Einmischung auf dem Balkan beteiligt.

Can I use *nichtsdestoweniger/gleichwohl*? Would it be weird with *nichtsdestoweniger/gleichwohl*?

Comment: Not to forget: [nichtsdestominder](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nichtsdestominder) :D

Comment: See also http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5313/1224

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Nichtsdestoweniger" as well as "gleichwohl" are uncommon and would indeed feel weird for a German. "Trotzdem" is by far the most commonly used word.

Comment: "jedoch" is also quite popular..

Comment: jedoch nicht immer gleichbedeutend.. (trotzdem cannot be used here ;) )

Answer (score 2):

"Nichtsdestotrotz" und "Trotzdem" are best suited in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything wrong with "dennoch"? It's very common.